# My logout page cookie is not destroying? Why is that?

Tags: php, cookies

```
**<?php
@session_start();
session_unset();
unset($_SESSION["user_email"]);
unset($_SESSION["user_id"]);
unset($_SESSION["verifyId"]);
$_SESSION["verifyId"]="";
$_SESSION["user_id"]="";
unset($_SESSION["ClientverifyId"]);
$_SESSION["ClientverifyId"]="";
setcookie("mpsUser_id","", time() - 3600,"../");
unset($_COOKIE["mpsUser_id"]);
$_COOKIE["mpsUser_id"] ="";
setcookie("mpsClient_id","", time() - 3600,"../");
unset($_COOKIE["mpsClient_id"]);
$_COOKIE["mpsClient_id"] ="";
session_destroy();
header("Location: login_signin.php?msg=logout!!!");
exit;
?>**
```

This is my site COOKIE and SESSION destroy code but here SESSION is destroying but is not destroying please help me to fixed this issues...

Comment: I think your problem really is the path not being set: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Remove this from the code and try again*
    `$_COOKIE["mpsUser_id"] ="";`

*or change the sequence like this*

```
setcookie("mpsClient_id","", time() - 3600,"../");
$_COOKIE["mpsClient_id"] ="";
unset($_COOKIE["mpsClient_id"]);
```